# css background-image partial width opacity

Tags: html, css

How to create a partial width opacity ?

I have a div that has a background image with transparency, I used after to do get the effect like this

```css
.indicators-menu {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1;
}

.indicators-menu::after {
  background-image: url('bg_platform_repeat.jpg');
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.9;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: unset;
}
```

This works great, but what I need to do is to split the opacity by width 
instead of 100% to 80% with opacity 0.9 and 20% with opacity 1

I thought to use the CSS mask property but I see that its not well supported

Comment: I will be better if you post your relevant HTML

Comment: Hey there, your explanation nor your code is helping. Post an inspirational image or full code you have tried.

Comment: Use two pseudo elements (add `::before`) , make one 80% and one 20% wide, and position them accordingly ...?

Comment: i tried every answer in here but i didn't work for me. maybe because my main div is in absolute. i added the main div css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what i need to do is to split the opacity by width instead of 100% to 80% with opacity 0.9 and 20% with opacity 1

Use *two* pseudo-elements with the same background image but position them differently.

```css
div {
  width: 460px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

div:before {
  width: 80%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* for example */
}

div:after {
  width: 20%;
  left: 80%;
  background-position: 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use an overlay above the image to simulate this effect. The color used need to be the same as the below background:

```css
.box {
  background: 
   linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.3),rgba(255,255,255,0.3)) left/80% 100%,
   url('https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069') center/cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:before` with `background: white;` and `opacity:0.1`(I set `0.4` only you to see the difference) and `width:80%`

```css
.indicators-menu::after,.indicators-menu::before{
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/BK7wL0d.jpg');
  content: "";
  opacity:1;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: unset;
}
.indicators-menu::before{
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;

}
```

```html
<div class="indicators-menu">

</div>
```